# iOS More Than One Unwind Segues on a Button

Tags: ios, segue

In my app I have a Done button.

Depending on which screen the user came from (namely a saved list screen or a new list screen) I'd like the Done button to use a different unwind segue.

Is this possible - if so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to IOS, but as per my knowledge, the simplest thing you can do is to create macros in your AppDelegate with different states and set a property whose value will be set according to those states, so that you can perform segue depending on the current status of the property. You can do like this:

```
//in AppDelegate.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#define SAVED_LIST_SCREEN   1
#define NEW_LIST_SCREEN     2

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) int  previousScreen;

@end
```

You can set the property "previousScreen" as SAVED_LIST_SCREEN or NEW_LIST_SCREEN depending on your current screen. And then you can check in "if codition" whether the previous state is Saved List or New List. And you can perform the segue operation accordingly.

```
if(app.previousScreen == SAVED_LIST_SCREEN)
{
 //perform 1st segue
}
else
{
  //perform 1st segue
}
```

Check it out and please let me know if it works.